# String Paramater in MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, procedure

I have what I hope is a simple question involving creating the SELECT query with a string parameter in a MySQL stored procedure and subsequently passing a CALL query from within PHP. This is from a login page and is therefore calling the procedure for login.  'Wowcrofty' in the error is the username.  The stored procedure I am using is included below.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE retrieve_user_info (IN username VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM db.dbo WHERE user_username=username;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

This is how I am calling the procedure from PHP.

```
$result = $conn->query("CALL retrieve_user_info($enteredusername)");
```

I have loaded the page containg the query and this is the error I am receiving.

> Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown column 'wowcrofty' in 'field list'

I have created a few other stored procedures and they are working perfectly.  However, this is the first one that uses a string as a parameter.  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: You should find this URL helpful to assist your effort.  
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx 
Good luck, they do work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote the parameter:

```
query("CALL retrieve_user_info('$enteredusername')");
```

Or better, use the library to prevent [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
stmt = $connection->prepare("CALL retrieve_user_info(?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $enteredusername);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: This is open to SQL injection, use a prepared statement.

Comment: @Barmar already there :)